# Creating a 2D Array in MIPS with Single Point numbers

Tags: mips

I am struggling to understand how to create a 2D array in MIPS using Single Point numbers.
I get how to create a 2D array by itself but can not figure out how to make it able to have single point numbers instead of just integers.

Comment: Please share the code you have already tried. What is the result/error you are getting and What must be the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Single precision floating point numbers are 4 bytes long just like integer words, 4 bytes long.  An array, whether 1D or 2D or 3D.., whether characters/bytes, integers or single precision floating point, simply uses memory — as much memory as needed for all the elements in the array.

Memory doesn't care how you use the bytes — it is up to the program to use the array in a meaningful way.  If you want to copy the array to another memory location, the equivalent of `memcpy` or `memmove` is appropriate.  If you want to do floating point arithmetic on elements of the array, then you would use floating point instructions.

Basically you don't have to do anything except have some memory to have single precision floating point array.  You might want to initialize the array, though if it is declared as a global array (e.g. using `.space 400`), all the bytes will be zero in value, and that corresponds to the integer 0 as well as the floating point value 0.0.  Just like an integer array, you would want the array to start aligned on a 4 byte boundary, which `.space` does not do, but `.align 2` in front of that will work.